# How can i create a documentation to my classes and methods in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, documentation, android-studio

I'm new to android world, i was wondering if there is a way to a documentation to my class, so when i hover on the class object i will be able to retrieve the description like in the following image

[image]

in visual studio all i have to do is something like this :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the Documentation 
    /// </summary>
```

i have tried this and it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's `javadoc`. You should type

```
/**
 *
 */
```

before the method declaration

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/javadoc.html) you can find more information

Comment: i tried to add this right above my class and it didn't work

Comment: this is what i get http://content.screencast.com/users/minagabriel/folders/Snagit/media/575ec3d4-5c82-474b-a94d-aebbcaee08ff/10.02.2014-16.04.png

Comment: can you try with a method ?

Comment: Yes it works with constructors isn't this strange!

Answer (score 5):

Feature you are talking about called JavaDoc:

```
/**
* This method adds two numbers
* @param a my param a
* @param b my param b
* @return result description
*/
public int add(int a, int b){
......
```

Details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html).

Comment: Thanks Works fine here is your first +1 welcome to Stackoverflow